# iPhone: Is there a special mimetype for iPhone downloads?

Tags: iphone

One of my clients got hamstrung by a developer who left them with a partially completed site using Wordpress.

One of the pages has a download page where a provisional profile and the app is downloaded from.  Is there something special that one must do to have the provisional profile be installed on a person's iPhone/iPad and is there a special mimetype or action that must be called from the webpage that allows for the install of the app?

Or must the app be in iTunes and then downloaded?

Download page is: http://gator1147.hostgator.com/~betterk/styledefinedapp.com/download/

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

That isn't really how you're supposed to do over-the-air ad hoc installs.  You're supposed to link to a plist file via an `itms-services` pseudo-protocol.  The link should look something like this:

`<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://example.com/ manifest.plist">Install App</a>`

The IPA file should be served as `application/octet-stream` and the plist should be served as `text/xml`.

For more details, see [Installing Apps Wirelessly](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009979-CH1-SW11).

The provisioning profile should be embedded in the IPA.  This provisioning profile *must* specify your client's device's UDID, otherwise it will fail to install.

The provisioning profile will expire after two months of it being created.  You can check the expiry date when the provisioning profile is installed on a device through the Settings app.  In order for the app to continue to run on the devices it is installed on, you will need to digitally sign the app with a new provisioning profile, which you will need a paid developer account for.

Comment: No problem.  If you need to build the plist manifest file, [iOS Beta Builder](http://www.hanchorllc.com/2010/08/24/introducing-ios-beta-builder/) should be the best option for you if you don't have an iOS developer to hand.

Comment: @Jim
iOS Beta Builder generates '/manifest.plist' instead of 'http ://example.com/ manifest.plist'  Is this valid?